# $emit and $broadcast alternative to non-existence controller

Tags: angularjs

I have encountered a situation where the angular plugin i am using only allow for language change on the $scope in its controller itself during runtime.

And the problem that i am having here is that some of the controller will not be exist until the view is switch but i need to ensure that the language of the plugin is switch when i change the language in the header.

Summarize: 
How can I emit and broadcast to non-existence controller(where the controller will only be available after view switching). Note that ChildAController, ChildBController, .., ChildZController is of separate view.

```
angular.module('parent').controller('HeaderController', function($scope) {
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (language) {
        // trigger $scope.changePluginLanguage in every controller
        // where ChildAController and ChildBController is of different view (and non-existent at the time)
    }
}

angular.module('childA').controller('ChildAController', function($scope, CustomPlugin) {
    $scope.changePluginLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.pluginOptions.LanguageUrl = language + ".json";
    }
}

angular.module('childB').controller('ChildBController', function($scope, CustomPlugin) {
    $scope.changePluginLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.pluginOptions.LanguageUrl = language + ".json";
    }
}

...
...

angular.module('childZ').controller('ChildZController', function($scope, CustomPlugin) {
    $scope.changePluginLanguage = function(language) {
        $scope.pluginOptions.LanguageUrl = language + ".json";
    }
}
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="HeaderController">
            <select ng-click="changeLanguage">
                <option ng-click="changeLanguage('English')">English</option>
                <option ng-click="changeLanguage('Spanish')">Spanish</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>

// View A
<div ng-controller="ChildAController">
    <CustomPlugin pluginOptions="pluginOptions"></CustomPlugin>
</div>

// View B
<div ng-controller="ChildBController">
    <CustomPlugin pluginOptions="pluginOptions"></CustomPlugin>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you changing views?  It looks like this isn't a `SPA`

Comment: @Malkus oops i have update the code. The ```<div ui-view></div>``` part is the view changing part. angular ui router is being used.

Answer (score 0):

> $emit and $broadcast alternative

Use `$watch` and **service** to save the value of the current language.

Client controller

```
angular.module('childA').controller('ChildAController', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.$watch(MyService.languageGet, function (language) {
        $scope.pluginOptions.LanguageUrl = language + ".json";
    }
}
```

The **factory service**

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("MyService", function() {
    var language = "default";
    function getLanguage() {
        return language;
    };
    function setLanguage(value) {
        language = value;
        return value;
    };
    return { getLanguage: getLanguage,
             setLanguage: setLanguage
    };
});
```

In the parent controller (or any controller), you can set the language.

```
MyService.setLanguage(newLanguage);
```

When a client controller is instantiated, the `$watch` will set the language, and then on each digest cycle, it will check the language setting and update if necessary.

For more information on `$watch`, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).